# SQL Query Compare value from multiple rows and get count

Tags: sql

I have following data in a table. I need the count of Pro, Assist, Spec  based on PID and the PID should be consider based on the below condition.
PRO > ASSIST > Spec

PID table

[image: PID Table]

I need the below result
PID Result

[image: PID Result]

Comment: Please tell which RDBMS you are using and its version as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SELECT  
 Id,
 PID,
 (SELECT COUNT(Ptext) FROM PIDTable WHERE Ptext='PRO' AND PID=P.PID AND ID=P.ID)  AS [Pro Count],
 (SELECT COUNT(Ptext) FROM PIDTable WHERE Ptext='Assist' AND PID=P.PID AND ID=P.ID)  AS [Assist  Count],
 (SELECT COUNT(Ptext) FROM PIDTable WHERE Ptext='Spec' AND PID=P.PID AND ID=P.ID)  AS [Spec  Count] 
FROM PID_Table AS P
```

Comment: It is counting the PID value for all the ptext. my condition is if PID exists in pro it should not be consider for assist and spec

Answer (score 0):

Most RDBMS support the [case](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) statement which you can use to get the desired result.
Here is a code sample:

```
SELECT Id, PID, SUM(case when Ptext= 'Pro' then 1 else 0 end) as ProCount  from PID
GROUP BY Id, PID
```

Comment: how do you give the preference to ```PRO > ASSIST > Spec``` with your query

Comment: I just provided a sample to get the ProCount. For other columns it's possible to use the same approach with different string literal

Comment: This will not work as I have entries in different row . I need to convert to columns and then take a count based on condition PRO > ASSIST > Spec

Answer (score 0):

You can use below syntax if you are using MS SqlServer.

```
SELECT ID, pid
            --,List_Output
              , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('PRO',List_Output) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ProCount
              , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('PRO',List_Output) = 0 AND  CHARINDEX('Assit',List_Output) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AssitCount
              , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('PRO',List_Output) = 0 AND  CHARINDEX('Assit',List_Output) = 0 AND CHARINDEX('Spec',List_Output) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SpecCount
FROM(
SELECT  ID,Pid
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(ptext AS VARCHAR(10)) [CVAL]
         FROM TEST 
         WHERE ID = t.ID AND pid=T.pid
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
FROM TEST t
GROUP BY ID,pid
) A
```

Source data:

[image]

Output:

> Prefernce : PRO > ASSIST > Spec

[image]

Answer (score 0):

with this query you can count in each ptext and pid you then you can show in each column topics:

```
 SELECT id,pid,COUNT(ptext) as counted FROM PID GROUP BY ptext,pid
```